# Incompatible types: Card cannot be converted to java.lang.String

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, while-loop, findfirst

I keep getting this error with my code. I can't seem to find the problem.

I'm not sure what to do because I even looked in the text book and it gives me a similar method except with different variables.

I'm on BlueJ.

```
 public int findFirstOfPlayer(String searchString)
{
    int index = 0;
    boolean searching = true;
    while(index < cards.size() && searching) {
        String cardname = cards.get(index); // Error highlights index
        if(cardname.contains(searchString)) {
            searching = false;
        }
        else {
            index++;
        }
        if(searching) {
            return -1;
        }
        else {
            return index;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try `cards.get(index).toString();` instead?

Comment: What is `cards`? Can you give details on the implementation?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of details. I'm making a card collection with an ArrayList<Card> cards;

Answer (score 2):

Here is the problem, and if you used something like Eclipse or Idea, it would even highlight it for you.

```
    String cardname = cards.get(index);
```

Obviously, cards is not compatible with String, you can't just assign it that way, because your collection card is probably not of type String aka `ArrayList<String> cards`
You can do either:

```
    String cardname = cards.get(index).toString();
```

or

```
    String cardname = String.valueOf(cards.get(index));
```

Comment: When I do cards.get(index).toString() it gives me a missing return statement and highlights the last bracket I put in the original post.

Comment: add ```return index;``` at the end

Answer (score 1):

Given that Card is a class on its own you can't compare it to string. You have to either implement a method that returns a string you can compare with `searchString` or use a variable within the card object for the comparisson. 
Something like this:

```
String cardname = cards.get(index).toString();
```

Or

```
String cardname = cards.get(index).name
```

Comment: When I do cards.get(index).toString() it gives me a missing return statement and highlights the last bracket I put in the original post.

Comment: Add a return statement between the two last brackets, as the while loop isn't guarranteed to run Java considers the option that it doesn't in which case your method would be missing a return statement.